# What is a linear resolution?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

Can anyone tell me where I may find an introduction to linear resolutions (of a $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$-module or ideal) including, of course, the standard definition of such a resolution, as well as its basic properties?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find some things about the linear free resolutions in the book of Bruns and Herzog, Cohen-Macaulay Rings.

Comment: You can look into [*Graded Syzygies*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Graded-Syzygies-Algebra-Applications-Irena/dp/0857291769), by Irena Peeva

Comment: Here is a simple and short lecture note by Tom Marley. 
https://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf